# auto size textarea / xp:inputTextarea - onload

Tags: javascript, textarea, xpages

I have applied autosize (http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) on a xp:inputTextarea but I notice this only works in edit mode and I have to update the content.

Is there a way to autosize the xp:inputTextarea in read mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a slightly approach: Hide the text area control in read mode and show the text inside a div. That way it will render to its full length whatever that might be. 
Users typically appreciate when you avoid double scroll bars when reading

Comment: hi Stephen, that is exactly what I did, display it via a computed text control, added a custom converter for the breaklines and apply Bootstrap form-control css properties to the computed text.